# Deviance of a larger model is much larger than the deviance of the reduced(nested) model

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, deviance

I am doing a logistic regression with 8 variables but for some reason the model with the second degree of interaction has a much larger deviance than the nested model without interaction. Because of that the likelihood ratio test for nested models gives me a negative Chi-Squared value and i don't quite know how to interpret these results. Anyone knows why this would be possible?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Did you code this in R’s `lmtest::lrtest`? I’ve definitely gotten negative degrees of freedom in that function by not paying attention to the order in which I input the models. The p-value is correct either way, however.

Comment: Can you post the results of `summary` for both models

Comment: The summary output is quite long because of how many variables there are but i do get this error when i do the regression for the larger model :" 1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge"

Comment: At least you need to show us the most relevant parts of the output!